# using HTTPS with node in portable APP, or not

Tags: node.js, ssl

Im developing a small Desktop application that make rerquest to other clients and have 2 parts:

The first one is a http server (using node http.createServer()) that serve the endpoint responses to the other clients

The other are a request system to make request to multiple clients to the previous endpoints using node request library

The code is actually working, but recently im asking myself if is a good one change to https or not, because the data served are not critical or need to be "hidden", but can be a god one to have it.
But I have 2 problems right now:

1º The application connects to to website endpoints to retrieve data, some times this websites can have SSL (https)

2º If i swith the local application server to HTTPS, how I can create a selfsigned certificated without end of life? (Because is a Desktop application) and if I create it in some way, is "retarded" use it because all people that have the application have the client/secrent and the security part is lose...

Im thinking in similar applications and all work with sockets, but I need to server JSON over http to allow web server/clients access it, so im really dont know if I need to swith to SSL or other thing... need a advice for this, all comments are appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you're unsure which question you should ask. It's rather simple, do you need IDENTITY VERIFICATION and TRANSPORT SECURITY between the client and server? If both components run on the same machine, you don't, otherwise yes, you do. Buy a proper certificate from a trusted authority, self-signed certs are for development only (arguably not even there).

Comment: In the general cases i dont need that, but exist an option to enable authenticate request, and in this case can be interesting. About the certificate, I continue with 2 problems, frist is the certificate time, its posible make a certificate for, for example, 10 years? if the answer is yes, i have the second problem, because the certificate need to be in the users machine, all users have the same, (and because the users are client AND server at same time) the pub/priv keys are in the users machine and allow to any decript the SSL trafic, correct? In this case i need to implement other system.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, why would you install a certificate in the client app if all you want to do is secure transport over the Internet? TLS, as the name implies, deals with Transport.

Comment: I know, but how I can get security transport over client and server if the users are the 2 at the same time (every client application "ask" and "give" responses to other clients), i think in this case i dont need to use SSL, i need something like specific keys per client connected, because like you say, I cant allow SSL connection without expose the secrets

Comment: So this is a peer to peer application? What protocol is it using for messaging to other peers?

Comment: actually http, is a "weird" P2P because are only endpoints in the clients, to send lists and other things, and i need to use http because part of the request can be done by other web servers and not clients only